# Creating a sprite in a different file (in a class)

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am looking for help creating a sprite in a different class and file cocos2d-x. I have used the code from the cocos2d-x website for subclassing a sprite and other posts and It would not work for me. I have followed the sonar systems tutorial for making a separate class for a "bird" sprite ("Player" in my case) and am having trouble with an error when trying to pass the helloworld layer through the Player class constructor that takes a parameter of a layer. the error says: "'Player::Player(const Player &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'HelloWorld *const ' to 'const Player &'    ApocalypseWorld c:\cocosprojects\apocalypseworld\classes\helloworldscene.cpp    39"

here is the code: 
 Player.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "cocos2d.h"

class Player
{
public:
 Player( cocos2d::Layer* layer );

private:
 cocos2d::Sprite *player1;
};
```

Player.cpp:

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "cocostudio/CocoStudio.h"
#include "ui/CocosGUI.h"

USING_NS_CC;

Player::Player( cocos2d::Layer* layer )
{

    player1 = Sprite::create("PlayerHead.png");
    player1->setPosition(Point(200, 200));

    layer->addChild(player1, 100);
}
```

HelloWorldScene.h:

```
#ifndef __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__
#define __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__

#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "Player.h"

class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:
    // there's no 'id' in cpp, so we recommend returning the class instance pointer
    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();

    // Here's a difference. Method 'init' in cocos2d-x returns bool, instead of returning 'id' in cocos2d-iphone
    virtual bool init();

    Player* player;

    // implement the "static create()" method manually
    CREATE_FUNC(HelloWorld);
};

#endif // __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__
```

HelloWorldScene.cpp:

```
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "cocostudio/CocoStudio.h"
#include "ui/CocosGUI.h"

USING_NS_CC;

using namespace cocostudio::timeline;

Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    auto scene = Scene::create();

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    auto layer = HelloWorld::create();

    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto rootNode = CSLoader::createNode("MainScene.csb");

    addChild(rootNode);

player = new Player(this);


return true;
```

}

i get a little red squigly line under the t in:

```
player = new Player(this);
```

at the end of the HelloWorldScene.cpp file

Comment: What and why you want to achieve by subclassing the Sprite class?

Comment: So i can separate different sprites into different files and so i can give them their own functions. @Jain

Comment: So what kind of problem you are having? Could you share some code?

Comment: @Jain I added code and the error. im not subclassing anymore, but creating a whole new class for the sprite.

Comment: Have you tried to change Player::Player( cocos2d::Layer* layer ) for Player::Player( HelloWorld& layer )?

Comment: @AlexG.G. Still not working

Comment: Do you have any other class with the same name Player. Or may be a struct?? Try renaming the class

Comment: I concur with Jain - it looks like you have a different definition for Player that is being picked up.

Answer (score 0):

Edited code:

Player.h:

```
#ifndef __Sample__Player__
#define __Sample__Player__

#include "cocos2d.h"

USING_NS_CC;

class Player : public Node
{
public:
    static Player* createPlayer(Layer* layer);

    Sprite* head;
};

#endif
```

Player.cpp:

```
#include "Player.h"

Player* Player::createPlayer(Layer* layer) {
    auto ret = new (std::nothrow) Player;
    if(ret && ret->init()) {
        ret->autorelease();
        ret->head = Sprite::create("PlayerHead.png");
        ret->addChild(ret->head);
        layer->addChild(ret, 100);
        return ret;
    }
    CC_SAFE_RELEASE(ret);
    return nullptr;
}
```

Then in your scene.h:

```
#include "Player.h"
```

And in your scene.cpp:

```
auto player = Player::createPlayer(this);
addChild(player);
```

Comment: i changed my code to this and i get the red squigly line under "this" in "this->addChild(head);" and "layer->addChild(this,100);"  saying "'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member function..."

Comment: ah sry, my bad. You should use ret->addChild(head) instead.

Comment: now have red squiggly line under "head" in " head = Sprite::create("PlayerHead.png");" and "this->addChild(head);" . it says: "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object"

Comment: Again my bad :D It ofc should be ret->head = Sprite::create("PlayerHead.png");

Comment: One last thing, in "auto player = Player::create(layer);" i get another error saying "no suitable constructor exists to convert from 'cocos2d::Layer *" to 'Player'"

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess it's because of that "create" method already exists in Node. Try renaming create to createPlayer function.

Comment: now i have same error as my second comment on this answer under head again. "ret->addChild(head);"
    "layer->addChild(head, 100);"